# Phonegap local directory select

Tags: android, ios, file, cordova

How to save a file to a specific directory with Phonegap?

I'm new to Phonegap, and the file API is driving me crazy!...
When this code runs I get error 5 (encoding error), the file on the console log seems correct... Please help!

I'm trying the following code:

```
function saveToFile() {
  window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFSSuccess, onFSError);
}

function onFSSuccess(fileSystem) {    
  var filePath = cordova.file.dataDirectory + 'test.txt';
  console.log(filePath);
  fileSystem.root.getFile(filePath, {create:true, exclusive:false}, gotFileEntry, onFSError);
}

function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
  console.log('Save to: ' + fileEntry.toURL());
  alert('Save to: ' + fileEntry.toURL());
  fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, onFSError);
}

function gotFileWriter(writer) {
    writer.onwrite = function(evt) {
      console.log('Write success!');
      alert('Write success!'); 
    };
  writer.write('Imperyal Test!');
}

function onFSError(err) {
  alert(err.code);
}
```

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: I'm trying to target android and ios. That's why I'm using cordova.file.dataDirectory, it is read/write on both...

Comment: can you log the app and say where you get this error?

Comment: I'm getting the error on fileSystem.root.getFile

Comment: dont have the device to try now but, if you didnt, look at here https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/doc/index.md. it was working to me

Comment: That's the page I was using, and http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.4.1/phonegap_file_file.md.html also. The code seems correct...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your app loads cordova.js and that the file is present in your platform project.  Check the console to see if cordova.js isn't found on load. Make sure your calling `saveToFile` in the onDeviceReady event handler.

In this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22170064/write-read-to-file-in-cordova-hybrid-android-app) the user was missing cordova.js from the project.

I don't see errors in your code. Sometimes when a plugin misbehaves, simply running the add script again fixes issues. Try running

```
 cordova plugins add org.apache.cordova.file
```